# Renaming files containing digits cygwin

Tags: linux, file, cygwin, rename

I am storing a number of images in my folder and some of them have filenames like `12412421_3843114_12412412`. There are 200-300 of such files and I want to be able to assign a  simply `a-zA-Z` sort of sequence, i.e, no numbers or underscores. How can I do this in cygwin?

**EDIT** I want the filenames to look anything like `abdllwlaslf`, but they need to be **without underscores**. I know my option is limited when I don't use underscores but for my case that's all I need.

Comment: Could you give some more details on what you're looking for? Do you want to prepend all the filenames of that format with something? Map the digits to specific letters? Taking the filename you pasted in your question, for instance, what would you want it to look like after it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming just replacing 0 with a, 1 with b etc, you could use `tr`:

```
$ echo 42344234_1341264574_2134234 | tr 0123456789_ abcdefghij
ecdeecdejbdebcgefhejcbdecde
```

Instead of `echo`, just pipe your filenames through and use the results for a rename.

Answer (score 1):

It won't produce very pretty filenames, but technically this would do what you want...

`for i in $( find . -regex ".*/[0-9_]+$" ) ; do mv $i $( basename $i | sed 'y/0123456789_/ABCDEFGHIJK/' ) ; done`

A file named `12412421_3843114_12412412` would become `BCEBCECBKDIEDBBEKBCEBCEBC` using the above. You could tweak the chars in the `sed` replacement if you wanted to.

Note that the command as above must be run from within the folder in question.

On a real Linux system, this could be done more efficiently using the `rename` command, but I haven't had good success using `rename` in Cygwin.